# How to catch error thrown by browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, frontend

In my case, I want to have a function that would be called on a different type of Error thrown by browser (RefferenceError, TypeError etc.).

I've tried solution with **window.onerror** but that doesn't work.

```
window.onerror = function(message, file, line) { }
```

Maybe someone has any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks

Comment: @JonasLochmann Try/catch  is not good in my case, because I don't know what kind of error will be thrown by browser during runtime

Comment: "but that doesn't work." - what does that mean? Errors in console?

Comment: @mplungjan
I mean that event **window.onerror** wouldn't be fired when for example in some of JS files would be called Function that doesn't exist and browser at that moment throw the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: fakeFunc is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):34)`

Comment: @JonasLochmann
yes it will catch, but in my case, I don't know where in my code will be thrown an error and I need "error lister" to track errors I think